# Decorative pattern versus monkey-patching in Python

Tags: python

Decorative pattern in Python allows to wrap the core object with other object capable of changing its behavior. It is also suggested that monkey-patching can be used to achieve similar effect? How does two compare? When is decorative pattern more useful than monkey-patching when used for the same task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between using the decorative pattern and monkey patching is that monkey patching can lead to hard-to-debug code. The problem is that monkey patching does not explicitly show the fact that you modified the class: users/readers/maintainers might be confused by the fact that the patched class behaves differently from what they expect (i.e. from the original class). I would recommend sticking to the decorative pattern, for code maintainability.